# How to add more objects to existing Angular Model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

First year angular user.  I have an existing angular object that holds json data.  How do we add more objects using angular?

I have the following code

**Updated!**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngTagsInput']);

var PageController = function ($scope) {

    $scope.models =   [{"text":"Tag1"},{"text":"Tag2"},{"text":"Tag3"}];
    };


$scope.AddModels = function (){
  if ($scope.models.length > 0) {
    $scope.addTag = function () {
      $scope.models.push([{"text":"Tag4"},{"text":"Tag5"},{"text":"Tag6"}]);
      console.log($scope.models);
    };

    $scope.addTag();
    }
}
```

**[Please see Plunker Sample Here!!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/pdxXhBwr4Xh3HuPBbj0k?p=preview)**

Comment: Why do you hold the JSON object as a string? What is the output you want to get?

Comment: Ok....I updated code.